# How does variables defined with `let` act inside a `for` loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, let

In the [documentation for the `let` statement in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), there's this example code:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));

  item.onclick = function (ev) {
    console.log("Item " + i + " is clicked.");
  };
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

Then they state:

> The example above works as intended because the five instances of the
>   (anonymous) inner function refer to **five different instances of the
>   variable i**.

I do not understand why there are "five different instances of the variable `i`.

The first statement in a `for` loop is always executed once, no?
So the `let` statement is supposed to only execute once...
Once the code reaches the end of the iteration it checks the condition in the second statement.

How come, according to what they write, there's a new instance of `i` on each iteration?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but I happened to test that behaviour last week and found that IE didn't implement it properly. (Chrome did.)

Comment: In ECMA 6 specification, when the let expression is used, every iteration creates a new lexical scope chained up to the previous scope. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation

Comment: To understand this, change that `let` to a `var` and see what happens when you click on the elements created by the loop

Comment: The first statement is executed only once, but I believe that the third statement (I++) equals to `let i = i + 1` and it is executed four times... is that correct?

Comment: @Jamiec, I understand *what* is happening, just not exactly *why*.

Answer (score 4):

When the let expression is used, every iteration creates a new lexical scope chained up to the previous scope.

This means that every closure captures a different instance.

That is according [ECMA 6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) but not sure it'll work same way in all browsers.

Also not sure about the performance implications. I'd rather use this feature carefully.

Comment: Before `let` IIFEs were used in order to achieve the same effect - with probably even worse performance. So what is your recommendation then?

Comment: @LUH3417 I'm just saying I'm `not sure` about the performance of such construct in different browsers. For example, have a look at this issue reported for chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4762

Comment: @LUH3417 and yes, probably iffy-s are even worse in terms of performance. So I'd better not recommend anything at all at this point

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, variables are traditionally **function-scoped**. Blocks, such as for...loop statements, do not create a new scope.

If you declare a variable using `var` anywhere in your function (for instance, in a for loop), it will be **declared only once at the top of the scope** thanks to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), and there will be only one instance of it in the entire function scope.

It can lead to issues when you invoke callbacks inside a for...loop.

```
// with hoisting, i is only declared once
for (var i in items) {  
    // the fn is called items.length times, before any callback is invoked
    _fetchItems(items[i], function() { 
        console.log("fetched for ", items{i]); 
        // for all callbacks, i is the same value items.length-1 
        // because they are called after the loop is complete
    });
}
```

Or in your example:

```
// with hoisting, i is only declared once
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

    // with hoisting, item is only declared once
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));

    // this function will be called after the for...loop is complete
    // so i value is unique: 5 + 1 = 6
    item.onclick = function (ev) {
        // => always return "Item 6 is clicked"
        console.log("Item " + i + " is clicked."); 
    };
    list.appendChild(item);
}
```

On the opposite, `let` variables are **only scoped to the nearest block** (ie. any code section between curly braces).

In your example, **a new instance of the variable `i` is declared** for each execution of the block inside the for...loop. `i`goes from 1 to 5, so there are 5 executions of the block, hence 5 instances of the variable.

They will each return the expected value "Item 1 is clicked.", "Item 2 is clicked.", etc.

Comment: The point is that first statement in a `for` loop is always executed once.
having it done as follows `for (var i = 1; i++; i < 5) { let t = i;  ...  }` would cause no questions.